# How does \halign differ from \hfil?

Tags: plain-tex

Suppose we have three blocks of text aligned horizontally. Why **Example 1** differs from **Example 2** and what should be changed in the latter to make it look like the former?

*NOTE:* I added rules just to indicate visually the placements of blocks of text.

**Example 1**

```
\def\text{%
  Inde igitur, inquit,
  ordiendum est. Tibi
  hoc incredibile, quod
  beatissimum.
}
\long\def\vtopragged#1#2{\vrule\kern-.4pt\vtop{\prevdepth=2pt\hsize=#1 \raggedright #2}\vrule\kern-.4pt}
\begingroup
\parindent=0pt
\tabskip=0pt
\topskip=0pt
\hrule
\kern-.4pt
\halign to\hsize{%
  \vtopragged{.2\hsize}{#}\tabskip=0pt plus 1fill &
  \vtopragged{.2\hsize}{#}\tabskip=0pt plus 1fill &
  \vtopragged{.2\hsize}{#}\tabskip=0pt \cr
  \text&
  \text&
  \text\cr
}
\hrule
\kern-.4pt
\endgroup
\bye
```

**Example 2**

```
\def\text{%
  Inde igitur, inquit,
  ordiendum est. Tibi
  hoc incredibile, quod
  beatissimum.
}
\long\def\parbox#1{%
  \vtop{
    \hsize0.2\hsize
    \parindent0pt
    \raggedright
    #1\par
  }%
}
\topskip=0pt
\hrule
\noindent
\vrule height 10pt
\parbox{\text}\hfil
\vrule
\parbox{\text}\hfil
\vrule
\parbox{\text}
\vrule
\hrule
\bye
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from the missing rules, the difference is that `\halign` doesn't care about `\parfillskip`, because it makes a box in vertical mode. You use `\hfil` in the second example, which can't kill `\parfillskip`. Things go smoothly if you use `\hfill`.

```
\def\text{%
  Inde igitur, inquit,
  ordiendum est. Tibi
  hoc incredibile, quod
  beatissimum.
}
\long\def\vtopragged#1#2{\vrule\kern-.4pt\vtop{\prevdepth=2pt\hsize=#1 \raggedright #2}\vrule\kern-.4pt}

\begingroup
\parindent=0pt
\tabskip=0pt
\topskip=0pt
\hrule
\kern-.4pt
\halign to\hsize{%
  \vtopragged{.2\hsize}{#}\tabskip=0pt plus 1fill &
  \vtopragged{.2\hsize}{#}\tabskip=0pt plus 1fill &
  \vtopragged{.2\hsize}{#}\tabskip=0pt \cr
  \text&
  \text&
  \text\cr
}
\hrule
\kern-.4pt
\endgroup
\bigskip

\long\def\parbox#1{%
  \vtop{
    \hsize0.2\hsize
    \parindent0pt
    \raggedright
    #1\par
  }%
}
\topskip=0pt
\hrule
\noindent
\vrule
\parbox{\text}\vrule\hfill\vrule
\parbox{\text}\vrule\hfill\vrule
\parbox{\text}\vrule
\hrule
\bye
```

[image]

Note that using `fill` units in `\tabskip` has no influence, because `fil` would suffice (`\halign to \hsize` is similar to `\hbox to \hsize`); compare the output when `fil` is used in the first example and `\hfil` in the second one, where the effect of `\parfillskip` is clearly seen.

[image]